# Accept Commas and Spaces In User Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, separator

I'm working on a program that accepts user input to calculate the mean, median, and mode. The issue is that I need to guess which separator the user will input.

For example:

```
def get_dataset():

    while True:

        try:
            dataset = [float(_) for _ in input("\nEnter Dataset: ").split()]
        except ValueError:
            print("\nInvalid Input")
            continue

        if len(dataset) < 2:
            print("\nPlease enter at least 2 values.")
        else:
            return dataset


print(get_dataset())


>>> Enter Dataset: 12 3 4
[12.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

I've only managed to check for spaces and tried to use `sep=', '` but the result is still the same except that it removes the brackets. Basically, what I'm trying to do is to get the program to accept input such as `1, 2, 3`, `1 2 3`, and `1,2,3`. Any other given separators will just result in an invalid input message.

Comment: Why not just replace commas with spaces before splitting?

Comment: Provide them with the format of input. E.g.: input("\nEnter Dataset in the following format [data_1, data_2,..] : "). This will give them the info on how to provide data according to your requirement.

Comment: Go slow: Read a line, examine it to figure out the format, then split it. Far better, and more extensible, than trying to pack everything into a "clever" one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comment, just replace comma `,` by space character   before splitting the input string.

```py
def get_dataset():

    while True:

        try:
            dataset = [float(_) for _ in input("\nEnter Dataset: ").replace(',', ' ').split()]
        except ValueError:
            print("\nInvalid Input")
            continue

        if len(dataset) < 2:
            print("\nPlease enter at least 2 values.")
        else:
            return dataset
```

#### SAMPLE RUN

```py
>>> print(get_dataset())
Enter Dataset: >? 12,3,4
[12.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: Then if I need to remove the brackets I can just write `print(*dataset, sep=', ')`, right? Or is there another way of doing so? Thank you by the way.

Comment: @RoyalFrog, you mean for printing? Yes

Comment: No no, like, currently in your sample run, the result is enclosed in brackets, I just need to remove that brackets, or is that a bad idea?

Comment: You can do `print(*get_dataset(), sep=',')`, it will remove the brackets while printing, and separate the values by comma

Answer (score 1):

You can do something a little more general (without using regex) with translate to do the replacement suggested.

```
def get_dataset():
    while True:
        dataset = []
        try:
            entered = input("Enter Dataset: ").\
                translate(str.maketrans(',:;', '   ')).\
                split(' ')
            dataset = [float(x) for x in entered if x != '']
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Input")
        if len(dataset) < 2:
            print("Please enter at least 2 values.")
        else:
            return dataset


print(get_dataset())
```

Gives something like

```
Enter Dataset: 1,4 , 5,
[1.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: Although it's a little longer than the first solution, it works wonders. I've also removed the looping part because the `if` statement is already handling empty values, and even if I remove the `if` statement, the exception handler will also handle it regardless, but right now, the exception handler is only handling non-numerical values.